# Rally sdk 2.1 - How to show leaf stories when cardboard rowconfig = PortfolioItem?

Tags: sdk, rally

I'm building a project story map using the cardboard. It should show all  bottom-level stories (ie stories without children and therefore iteration-able) by their iteration (column), with the option to set the row to the Epic (portfolio item) or Parent User Story (Parent).

The problem is when rowconfig = 'PortfolioItem', I only get immediate child stories of the Epic. When rowconfig = 'Parent', I get the bottom level stories, though suspect this is because I have at most one parent story so any child is bottom-level.

thought rowconfig was just a grouping config but seems to be filtering the query as well.

**ie given the following hierarchy:**

```
Epic A -> Story 1 -> Story aa
Epic A -> Story 1 -> Story ab
Epic A -> Story 2
Epic B -> Story 3
Story 4
Story 5 -> story cc
```

**What I want when grouping by the Epic**

```
Epic A
-------
Story aa, Story bb, Story 2

Epic B
-------
Story 3

None
-----
Story 4, Story 5
```

**what I get with rowconfig = 'PortfolioItem':**

```
Epic A
-------
Story 1, Story 2

Epic B
-------
Story 3

None
-----
Story 4, Story cc
```

**what I get with rowconfig = 'Parent':**

```
Story 1
-------
Story aa, Story ab

Story 5
-------
story cc

None
-----
Story 2, Story 3, Story 4
```

Is there a way to force the store to get the lowest level stories even when rowconfig is 'PortfolioItem'? In this case I can assume there is at most one parent between the Epic and the bottom level.

the actual code is here - for now I removed any filters.

```
me.StoryMapBoard = Ext.create('Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard',{
                //xtype: 'rallycardboard',
                types: ['User Story'],
                attribute: 'Iteration',
                context: this.getContext(),
                rowConfig: {
                    field: 'Parent' // switch to 'PortfolioItem' to show the Epic
                },
                cardConfig: {
                    fields: [
                              'Name',
                              'ScheduleState',
                              'Parent',
                              'DirectChildrenCount'
                    ]
                },

                listeners: {
                              load: me._onBoardLoaded,
                              scope: me
                              },

                storeConfig: {
                    //filters: myFilters,
                    context:{
                              project:'FOOBAR',  //not my actual project
                              projectScopeUp: false,
                              projectScopeDown: true
                            },
                }          

            });          
          me.add(me.StoryMapBoard);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your `rowConfig.field` to be `"Feature"`.  That field will be populated correctly for leaf stories and any epics in between.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work. With rowConfig.field as 'Feature' I get all the stories (yay!) but there are no rows, just columns. My project is a child project. In my scope I have Epics, and I have Stories which depending on size may be split into in a one-level parent/child hierarchy. Eventually the parent project to mine, which represents a program, will have Themes and Features. The guy running it isn't there yet, but those levels are reserved for him.

Comment: I solved it - was very simple, just needed rowconf field to be 'Epic'. I had tried that first but didn't seem to work, I guess there was a bug somewhere else that has gone now. Many thanks for your advice though, which I will definitely remember once Feature guy gets the Features in!

Answer (score 0):

Oops - Doh! Setting rowConfig.field to "Epic" worked. Thought I had tried that at the start and not got the right results... maybe  I mistyped it.